# Howto set custom ticks and labels on Y axis in nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'd like to set custom tick number and labels for my discrete chart done in nvd3. The problem is that labels and values needs to be shown in ratios like 10:1, 8:1 etc. but actual bar height shown as numbers 10, 8 etc. Is there any way to create custom labels on y axis and on mouse over tool-tips in nvd3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) (which is actually a raw D3 method):

```
chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return  d + ':' + 1;
    });
```

NVD3 will automatically use that format in the tooltip.

If you wanted to edit the tooltip content separately you could use the tooltipContent method (other methods will likely be added [in the next release of NVD3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/dbcdc25bd1637cbe5368a8e0f74032c1acafcb0f/src/tooltip.js)).

```
chart.tooltipContent(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
        '<p>' +  y + ' on ' + x + '</p>';
});
```

See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/njqao1HSMbCxGNTWE1c5?p=preview).