# How to configure nvd3 for Europe number formatting?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, nvd3.js, rcharts

This is not a coding-related issue. I'm fine using R + rCharts to create interactive visualisations. My question is about I cannot find documentation or forums that explain how to change nvd3 settings.

I have these charts:
http://www.fundacionsol.cl/2015/09/desposesion-salarial-chile/

My issue is about style. In Europe '.' is used for thousands and ',' for decimals (e.g 1 million = 1.000.000,00)

The plots are working perfect and I'd like to use the correct format (which is a minor thing). I've been looking on different forums and documents and I cannot make the proper change.

After some experiments, if I modify nv.d3.min-new.js I can change the 'grouped' and 'stacked' visualisation options. For example:

`{var F=[{key:"Grouped",disabled:t.stacked()},{key:"Stacked",disabled:!t.stacked()}`

for

`{var F=[{key:"Agrupado",disabled:t.stacked()},{key:"Aplilado",disabled:!t.stacked()}`

Displays the chart options in spanish. But I cannot change the decimals settings.
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into D3 locales https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Localization

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'm looking forward for that. I cannot find an nvd3 manual or documentation.

Comment: Localization is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tickFormat` function to change the way ticks are formatted (this is plain D3).

[Howto set custom ticks and labels on Y axis in nvd3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694406/howto-set-custom-ticks-and-labels-on-y-axis-in-nvd3/29785803#29785803)

`valueFormatter` might be what you're looking for in the case of tooltips.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/tooltip.js